# Using the space button on your phone as a button click

Tags: android

Is it possible to set an event when a user clicks spacebar in Android. 
Like if a user clicked on spacebar, perform a certain action

Comment: Could you please explain little more exactly what you want to do?

Comment: If you press space on your phone. I wont it to be like you press I button.  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    }

  });

Comment: Not getting your point....you can add listeners to any UI widget and override its onItemClickListener method and perform your task

Comment: As far as I understand all you want is to do some event when user presses the space bar in android keyboard, right??? If yes then override the method onKeyDown and when you get keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE do your stuff there.

Comment: I mean that if you are writing something in the app, then press space.I won´t the word that I'm writing to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean backspace button? If so, than:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.d(TAG,"here we are");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to do this.I put my cod in if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  but it didn't happened anything. Do you have any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

bind a TextWatcher to your EditText, and listen for the space character.

Edit: here's some code

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // put your magic here
  }
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }
});
```

Comment: I´m new to programing, can you give me an example please?